Short story about an alien form no one can communicate with
My mom remembers reading this when she was young, in the 80s. The ending describes the alien making contact with a blind man, telling him it will be his eyes.

Will you be able to tell if an answer is correct?

Someone else seems to be on the hunt for this; "I don't know if it's your story, but I remember a lot about a similar one. Alien turns out to be young and female. Her parents were exiled for "having their own minds" (telepathic) Defence lawyer quotes poem on Statue of Liberty "give me your tired, your poor". At the end the alien goes to live with a blind veteran, to "be his eyes". I can't remember the title or author though."

This appears to be “The Witness” by Eric Frank Russell, from Other Worlds, September 1951, reprinted in Russell’s collection Deep Space and no doubt elsewhere.  As the questioner said, “The ending describes the alien making contact with a blind man, telling him it will be his eyes.”  The end of this story describes a man who we learn indirectly is blind (he is described as trailing his hand along the wall, by implication to keep oriented) coming to answer his door, fingers then fumbling at the door=latch.  It ends:
“Then, finding it, they began to turn the lock, and at that point a thin piping voice came into his mind as clearly as a tinkling bell.
“ ‘Open please—I am your eyes!”
The earlier parts of the story are consistent with those quoted by Valorum: the alien is young and female, parents killed (not exiled) for “having minds of their own” as members of a species with a “racial mind”; defense lawyer quotes the poem on the Statue of Liberty; the alien goes to join a blind veteran, selecting from a torrent of requests from people who would like to have a telepathic alien living with them.  Most of the story takes place in a parodic trial in which the alien, named Maeth, is accused of various misdeeds including damaging a farm upon landing and damaging a diner’s windows to get food.  The Statue of Liberty motif is introduced by the defense lawyer’s purporting to call the Statue as a witness.
So it appears that both questions relate to the same story, and it is “The Witness.”  The text can be found here:
https://drive.usercontent.google.com/download?id=1DNZYaTx4Sr24x1KK0Q3NOcZeVnbfrGsA&export=download&authuser=0
at page 6 ff.

Yes! This is definitely it. ISFDB link here.

Thanks so much! It is the same story!!
